# Getting invalid_scope when attempting to obtain a refresh token via the Google API

Tags: java, oauth, gmail

I can't seem to be able to utilize the Google API with Oauth.  What am I missing?

**Error Message:**

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Invalid oauth scope or ID token audience provided."
}
```

**Java code:**

```
private void printLabels() {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\credential.json"));
    credential.createScoped(scopes);
    credential.refreshToken();      // error happens here

    String appName = "VS";
    Gmail.Builder builder = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(appName);
    Gmail gmail = builder.build();

    Object o = gmail.users().labels().list("me").execute();
    System.out.println("o = " + o);
}
```

**Google API Configuration:**

1. Logged in to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Created project
3. Enabled Gmail API
4. Created Service Account (assigned owner role)
5. Download json credentials file
6. Enabled OAuth consent screen - internal (not sure I need this since I only want to access my emails)
7. Enabled service account domain wide delegation (not sure I need this either)

Comment: It's a bit unclear on what you're trying to do, and this code is incomplete. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) say that refreshing a token is handled automatically.

Comment: Hello @ChristopherSchneider, thank you for your reply.  I updated my question with additional code that I have been using.  This is my first attempt at using the Google API so I am just aiming at printing labels.  To your point, I tried to skip the refreshToken() call since Google would handle automatically but ended up getting the same error further down, when calling the execute().  Do you see anything else that I would be missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: I have th same issue with revolution/laravel-google-sheets, have you found the solution?

Comment: @Mahefa you may add 'scopes' => [Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE, Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS],
in your google config

Comment: @keatwei thks, I will test this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`credential.createScoped(scopes)`

Returns a copy of credential object with the given scope.
You can verify this by `credential.getServiceAccountScopes()` and check if the scope is set.

Try assigning the value to credential object, like.

```
credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
```

Comment: From evening 9pm to early morning 4:20am, finally I read this answer. Initialising GoolgeCredentials with created scope is the trick 'credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);'. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was having that issue using Python `default()` to get the default credentials. It worked fine for the credentials loaded with `gcloud auth application-default login` or Kubernetes Workload Identity. But when using a Service Account file with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` I was having this issue when trying to call `credentials.refresh()`. I fixed the issue by explicitly providing the `scopes` parameter to `default()` function with the `['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']` scope.

So I changed from this:

```
from google.auth import default

credentials, _ = default()
```

To this:

```
from google.auth import default

credentials, _ = default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

Comment: THIS was the solution for me in python, though I still don't understand why scopes had to be added with the cloud-platform scope when I'm using the Cloud Runtime Configurator API.